# How to get all children of a parent control?

Tags: c#, .net, controls

I'm looking for an code example how to get all children of parent control.

I have no idea how do it.

```
foreach (Control control in Controls)
{
  if (control.HasChildren)
  {
    ??
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. How do you want to 'get' those controls, seeing as how you already know how to iterate through them?

Comment: You are already iterating the children with the foreach loop.  At least the children of this.Controls, presumably the form.  It isn't otherwise clear what you mean with "parent control".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you only want the immediate children, use

```
...
var children = control.Controls.OfType<Control>();
...
```

If you want all controls from the hierarchy (ie, everything in the tree under a certain control), use a pretty simple data-recursive method:

```
    private IEnumerable<Control> GetControlHierarchy(Control root)
    {
        var queue = new Queue<Control>();

        queue.Enqueue(root);

        do
        {
            var control = queue.Dequeue();

            yield return control;

            foreach (var child in control.Controls.OfType<Control>())
                queue.Enqueue(child);

        } while (queue.Count > 0);

    }
```

Then, you might use something like this in a form:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /// get all of the controls in the form's hierarchy in an IEnumerable<>
        foreach (var control in GetControlHierarchy(this))
        {
            /// do something with this control
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Controls have a `MyControl.Controls` collection which you can do a `foreach` on.

Each Control also has a `Parent` property which gives you the parent control.

You can write a recursive method if you need to go down an unknown number of levels.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it could be useful for someone:

```
public void GetControlsCollection(Control root,ref List<Control> AllControls,  Func<Control,Control> filter)
{
    foreach (Control child in root.Controls)
    {
        var childFiltered = filter(child);
        if (childFiltered != null) AllControls.Add(child);
        if (child.HasControls()) GetControlsCollection(child, ref AllControls, filter);
    }
}
```

This is recursive function to get the collection of controls with the possibility of appling filter (for expample by type). And the example:

```
 List<Control> resultControlList = new List<Control>();
 GetControlsCollection(rootControl, ref resultControlList, new Func<Control,Control>(ctr => (ctr is DropDownList)? ctr:null ));
```

It will return all DropDownLists in rootControl and his all children

Answer (score 1):

Probably overly complicated, but using Linq and some ideas from above / other places:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllChildren(this Control root) {
        var q = new Queue<Control>(root.Controls.Cast<Control>());

        while (q.Any()) {
            var next = q.Dequeue();
            foreach (Control c in next.Controls)
                q.Enqueue(c);

            yield return next;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a concise recursive extension function using Linq:

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Recursive function to get all descendant controls.
        /// </summary>
        public static IEnumerable<Control> GetDescendants(this Control control)
        {
            var children = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
            return children.Concat(children.SelectMany(c => GetDescendants(c)));
        }
```